# Azure Devops : Deploy Multiple Webjobs from for same project but different Connection string

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a scenario where i need to create 2 web jobs from the same Project (in .net core). I was able to do this with ease by creating 2 separate build artifacts (in build pipeline) and referred it in the release task. Each web job uses a different connection strings on its own.

The challenge here is: How do i configure the connection strings in release Pipeline variables as the Connection string Name is the same in appsetting.json file? Is there a way where i can configure the value of its respective connection string in each of its release task?

Comment: Hi @VarunR, how are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have a try with it. Any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [**Multi-job configuration**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-job-configuration) (**Matrix**) in your release pipeline.

A simple example:

- Add the pipeline variable with multiple values that are separated by comma.

  [image]
- Enable Multi-job configuration in the pipeline.

  [image]
- Run the pipeline.

  [image]

  [image]

**[UPDATE]**

If all the deployment jobs have the same steps (tasks) need to run, and the differences between the jobs only are the input values for some configurations on these tasks, you just need to set one job with these steps, and set up the multi-value pipeline variables, then enable the **Multi-job configuration** feature. Just like the example above.

If the deployment jobs have some same steps, but also have some steps only for certain jobs. You also can only set up one job that contains all the steps and enable the **Multi-job configuration** feature. For the steps that only required by certain jobs, you can specify some conditions under these steps to let them only run when the jobs are on the specified configurations. For more details, you can see "[**Specify conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

In a pipeline that contains multiple jobs, if most (even all) of the steps need to run between these jobs are same, you can use the **Multi-job configuration** feature. This feature aims to avoid copying the same steps between multiple jobs in a pipeline. You just need to set one job and add the steps once in the pipeline. When running the pipeline, it will automatically copy the job for each configuration. As you have seen in my above example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any settings that I need to do for the 2 jobs (Deployment job Connection 1 & Connection 2)? How does it picks up the multiple job configuration? What if i have other tasks in the same pipeline (like app service deploy task). Should we create a new stage for that?

Comment: Hi @VarunR, I have update mu answer with more details. Please check it. Any question about this, feel free to tell us.